# AngularJs Factory - Data not present within view Controller

Tags: angularjs, factory

I created some factorys in angular which are storing some data and providing some methods. If the view of my application changes, I've to check, if some data is present within the factorys and if the view is allowed to show up based on the data.

Within the method isAssessable I call method of another factory. $basket.getBasketTotal().value -> this method returns an empty value without delay. The value is stored within an property of the factory. The $basket factory has the same structure like the $bookingSteps it only contains othe values.

It seems that the data of the factory is not present if I call the factory methods from the view controller. If I debug it the data is present, because the debugging makes the execution slower. So for me it seems that the issues has something to to do with the lifecycle and the state of the factory.

If I wrap a $timeout arround and call the factory method with a delay the app behaves like expected. But this is not a very good solution.

Has anybody an idea how to fix that behavior?

```js
 app.controller('checkoutController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$bookingStepsFactory', function ($scope, $timeout, $bookingStepsFactory) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $bookingStepsFactory.isAssessable();
        }, 1500);



    }]);


app.factory('$bookingStepsFactory', ['$rootScope', '$route', '$location', '$rateSearchFactory', '$global', 'localStorageService', '$basket',
        function ($rootScope, $route, $location, $rateSearchFactory, $global, localStorageService, $basket) {

            /**
             * Stored the current visible booking step, the number of maximum steps available
             * and the routes for each step
             * @type {{currentStep: number, maxSteps: number, routes: Array}}
             */
            var bookingStepsSettings = {
                currentStep: 1,
                maxSteps: 5,
                routes: []
            }, numberOfProperties = 0, tmpMaxStepsFromRoutes = 0, key;

            //Number of hotels within this channel type
            numberOfProperties = $global.getHotelData().length;


            for (key in $route.routes) {
                if ($route.routes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if ($route.routes[key].bookingStep) {

                        //Find the highest step number within routes
                        if (tmpMaxStepsFromRoutes === 0) {
                            tmpMaxStepsFromRoutes = $route.routes[key].bookingStep;
                        } else if ($route.routes[key].bookingStep > tmpMaxStepsFromRoutes) {
                            tmpMaxStepsFromRoutes = $route.routes[key].bookingStep;
                        }

                        //If the minimum number of results needed for the route is lower than the number of hotels,
                        //add route to collection. If there is only one hotel, all routes needing mor than one result, will
                        //not be added. i.e. The hotel selection is not needed for one hotel.

                        if (!$route.routes[key].disabled && $route.routes[key].minResults && $route.routes[key].minResults <= numberOfProperties) {
                            bookingStepsSettings.routes.push({
                                step: $route.routes[key].bookingStep,
                                path: key,
                                minResults: $route.routes[key].minResults,
                                name: $route.routes[key].stepName,
                                disabled: $route.routes[key].disabled || false,
                                needItemsInBasket: $route.routes[key].needItemsInBasket || false
                            });
                        } else if (!$route.routes[key].disabled && !$route.routes[key].minResults) {
                            bookingStepsSettings.routes.push({
                                step: $route.routes[key].bookingStep,
                                path: key,
                                minResults: $route.routes[key].minResults,
                                name: $route.routes[key].stepName,
                                disabled: $route.routes[key].disabled || false,
                                needItemsInBasket: $route.routes[key].needItemsInBasket || false
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bookingStepsSettings.maxSteps = tmpMaxStepsFromRoutes;

            function save() {
                localStorageService.set('bookingStepsSettings', bookingStepsSettings);
                localStorageService.set('numberOfProperties', numberOfProperties);
            }

            function init() {
                var  date = localStorageService.get('rateDate'), obj,
                    currentDate = new Date();

                if (date) {
                    if (new Date(parseInt(date, 10)).getTime() + (5 * 60 * 1000) >= currentDate.getTime()) {
                        bookingStepsSettings = localStorageService.get('bookingStepsSettings');
                        numberOfProperties = parseInt(localStorageService.get('numberOfProperties'));
                    }
                    var current = $route.current.$$route.originalPath, numberOfSearchResults = $rateSearchFactory.resultsAvailable(), i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < bookingStepsSettings.routes.length; i++) {
                        if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].path === current) {
                            bookingStepsSettings.currentStep = bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].step;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            init();
            /**
             * Function that returns a route based on the step number
             * @param step (integer value between 1 and maxSteps)
             * @returns {*}
             */
            function getPath(step) {
                var i = 0, result;
                for (i = 0; i < bookingStepsSettings.routes.length; i++ ) {
                    if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].step === step) {
                        result = bookingStepsSettings.routes[i];
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            /**
             * Function that returns a route based on the min results. This is needed in case we get one result
             * in a channel with multiple hotels, to ignore the hotel selection
             * @param results
             * @returns {*}
             */
            function getStepByMinResults (results) {
                var i = 0, result;
                if (results === 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < bookingStepsSettings.routes.length; i++ ) {
                        if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].bookingStep === 1) {
                            result = bookingStepsSettings.routes[i];
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                } else {


                    for (i = 0; i < bookingStepsSettings.routes.length; i++) {
                        if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].minResults <= results) {
                            result = bookingStepsSettings.routes[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            /**
             * If location will change, check if the new URL is part of the booking steps. If yes, update the current
             * booking step.
             */
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
                for (var i= 0; i < bookingStepsSettings.routes.length; i++) {
                    if (newUrl.indexOf(bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].path) >= 0) {
                        if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].step) {
                            bookingStepsSettings.currentStep = bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].step;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            /**
             * This functions are needed to navigate to the next or previous booking step.
             * They are used i.e. by the search box, booking progress
             */
            return {

                /**
                 * Is used to navigate to the next booking step
                 */
                nextStep: function () {
                    if (bookingStepsSettings.currentStep < bookingStepsSettings.maxSteps) {
                        var numberOfSearchResults = $rateSearchFactory.resultsAvailable(), tmpStep;
                        tmpStep = getPath(bookingStepsSettings.currentStep + 1);
                        if (tmpStep.needItemsInBasket && $basket.getBasketTotal().value < 1) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (tmpStep.minResults) {
                            if (tmpStep.minResults <= numberOfSearchResults) {
                                bookingStepsSettings.currentStep = tmpStep.step;
                                $location.path(tmpStep.path);
                            } else {
                                tmpStep = getStepByMinResults(numberOfSearchResults);
                                bookingStepsSettings.currentStep = tmpStep.step;
                                $location.path(tmpStep.path);

                            }
                        } else {
                            $location.path(tmpStep.path);
                        }

                    }
                    save();
                },
                isAssessable: function() {
                    var current = $route.current.$$route.originalPath, numberOfSearchResults = $rateSearchFactory.resultsAvailable(), i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < bookingStepsSettings.routes.length; i++) {
                        if(bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].path === current) {
                            if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].needItemsInBasket && $basket.getBasketTotal().value < 1) {
                                $location.path(getPath(1).path);
                            }
                            if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].minResults) {
                                if (bookingStepsSettings.routes[i].minResults > numberOfSearchResults) {
                                    $location.path(getPath(1).path);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                },
                /**
                 * Is used to navigate to the previous booking step
                 */
                previousStep: function () {
                    if (bookingStepsSettings.currentStep < bookingStepsSettings.maxSteps) {
                        bookingStepsSettings.currentStep --;
                        $location.path(getPath(bookingStepsSettings.currentStep));
                    }
                    save();
                },
                /**
                 * Is used to navigate to a specific booking step
                 * @param step (Integer between 1 and maxSteps)
                 */
                goToStep: function (step) {
                    if (step < bookingStepsSettings.maxSteps) {
                        var numberOfSearchResults = $rateSearchFactory.resultsAvailable(), tmpStep;
                        tmpStep = getPath(step);
                        if (tmpStep) {
                            if (tmpStep.needItemsInBasket && $basket.getBasketTotal().value < 1) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (!tmpStep.minResults || tmpStep.minResults && tmpStep.minResults <= numberOfSearchResults) {
                                bookingStepsSettings.currentStep = tmpStep.step;
                                $location.path(tmpStep.path);
                            } else {
                                tmpStep = getStepByMinResults(numberOfSearchResults);
                                bookingStepsSettings.currentStep = tmpStep.step;
                                $location.path(tmpStep.path);

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    save();

                },
                /**
                 * This function returns a copy of all routes within the booking steps.
                 * @param step (Integer value between 1 and maxSteps)
                 * @returns {*} Copy of a route object
                 */
                getBookingRoutes: function () {
                   return angular.copy(bookingStepsSettings.routes);
                },
                getCurrentStep: function () {
                    return angular.copy(bookingStepsSettings.currentStep);
                }
            };


        }]);
```

Comment: without code, no answers

Comment: welcome to SO, you should provide relevant code in your question

Comment: You are most likely reloading the whole page and the whole AngularJS application itself.